# SharePoint left sided navigation

Tags: 2013, navigation

My colleague has been working on a website in SharePoint 2013. After some time the link to `Recent` documents disappeared. Because the project got to a stop and started again some time later, he couldn't remember exactly which options he modified.

Perhaps any of you guys know how to bring the link to recent documents back?
I would be very happy.

Kinds regards,

Comment: "recent" links are created automatically when you add a new app (list, library, etc.) to the site. They disappear after some time. You have an option to add permanent links yourself. You can see all the apps on a site in Site Contents page. Just find the library you're looking for and copy the URL to the link :)